# Cross compilation to embedded system

Tags: c

I'm new in embedded systems development. I just want to compile some C code for this system:

```
 uname -mrs
 Linux 2.6.32.28_stm24_0207 sh4
 machine         : STb7100 Reference board
 processor       : 0
 cpu family      : sh4
 cpu type        : STx7100
 cut             : 3.x
 cpu flags       : fpu
 cache type      : split (harvard)
 icache size     : 16KiB (2-way)
 dcache size     : 32KiB (2-way)
 address sizes   : 29 bits physical
 bogomips        : 264.19
```

Can anybody tell me the steps how to accomplish C compilation on my PC (Ubuntu) with GCC for that kind of system. I just need a little guidance.

Comment: check kpit toolchain http://www.kpitgnutools.com/

Comment: Basically, you need a "cross compiler" that is *hosted* on your PC and which *targets* the STb7100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=STx7100) indicates that chip has an ST40 cpu core.  Another google search turned up [this link](http://www.stlinux.com/install/getting-started/installing-gnu-tools) which has all of the instructions you need.

Comment: So OS in that system is STLinux ?

Comment: Looks that way - that's what your `uname` output seems to indicate you're using, too.

Answer (score 0):

Building a cross compiler is not trivial.  Having said that, should you march down that path at the end you will know a lot more about how the gcc compiler really works, there are, very likely, a bunch of things you don't know that you don't know here.  Then again, @Carl Norum has the easier path.  Bottom line, the former path is more rewarding, the latter is easier :-)

Comment: I'm working with great tutorial, to learn how things are working ;) https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/l-cross/l-cross-ltr.pdf

Comment: awesome, I think this will take you down the tunnel of linker scripts and the like, you will find, for example, that there is some start-up code that gets executed before main. Incidentally, don't let anyone dissuade you from understanding assembly, if you're dealing with this stuff you'll have little trouble sorting out assembly!

Answer (score 0):

You need a cross compiler so you can compile your app in your pc and download it to the device, the one suitable for that processor, for example the one for this : http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.avi-plus.com%2Fdownload%2FSTb7100MB.pdf&ei=DIbyUbXZGYay9gTB_4GYDg&usg=AFQjCNHaAj1_zgFosaQPmP1htiz9e6KGCw&sig2=TCVzRlWfaqcvyAjyU1jjsw&bvm=bv.49784469,d.eWU is Altera VHDL Compiler. After that you could need some kind of sdk.

Comment: errr, that's a link to a data sheet for a reference board.